# How can I add elements that are in strings inside a list?

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python. I would like to know if there is a way to sum string numbers inside a list.

For example, see the following list:

```
['2,1,4', '3,4,1', '70,20']
```

There are three string elements each one containing some numbers separated by comma. I want to get the sum of each element so that I get the following output.

```
[7, 8, 90]
```

I wrote the following function that doesn't work fully. It gives a wrong output:

```
def somma (lista):
    
    lista2 = []
    somma = 0
    
    for x in lista:
        for y in x.split(','):
            if y.isdigit():
                somma+=int(y)
        lista2.append(somma) 
            
    return lista2
```

Output:

```
[7, 15, 105]
```

Comment: Why did you not change your code so that it gives the correct output instead of the wrong output? Apparently the problem is that the previous value ends up being added to each value in the list (7 + 8 = 15, 90 + 15 = 105).

Comment: You set `somma = 0` only once outside the loops so why did you expect it to start over each time?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can use a generator:

```
lst = ['2,1,4','3,4,1','70,20']
lst = [sum(int(x) for x in i.split(',')) for i in lst]
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[7, 8, 90]
```

You can also use `map`:

```
lst = [sum(map(lambda x: int(x), i.split(','))) for i in lst]
```

Answer (score 2):

You nearly had it right with your code, you just need to move the somma variable into the first loop so it is set to 0 when you calculate the next string.

Your issue was somma already had the previous value when summing the next string.

```
def somma(lista):
    lista2 = []
    for x in lista:
        somma = 0
        for y in x.split(','):
            if y.isdigit():
                print(y)
                somma += int(y)
                print(somma)
        lista2.append(somma)

    return lista2
```

Comment: Oh, Thank you very much. As you can see it is a beginners mistake :D

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
def soma(lista):
    lista2 = [] 

    for x in lista: 
        lista2.append(sum([int(i) for i in x.split(',')]))
        
    return lista2
```